# Unable to parse the JSON document: Unrecognized token '$util': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to use a query with a filter:

```
query queryPitchesByApprovedIndex($approved: Boolean = true) {
  queryPitchesByApprovedIndex(approved: $approved) {
    items {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping template, made by AppSync, looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Query",
  "query": {
    "expression": "#approved = :approved",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#approved": "approved",
    },
    "expressionValues": {
      ":approved": {"B": $util.dynamodb.toBinary($ctx.args.approved)},
    },
  },
  "index": "approved-index",
  "limit": $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.first, 20),
  "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.after, null)),
  "scanIndexForward": true,
  "select": "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
}
```

The error I get is:

> Unable to parse the JSON document: 'Unrecognized token '$util': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (String)\"{\n  \"version\": \"2017-02-28\",\n  \"operation\": \"Query\",\n  \"query\": {\n    \"expression\": \"#approved = :approved\",\n    \"expressionNames\": {\n      \"#approved\": \"approved\",\n    },\n    \"expressionValues\": {\n      \":approved\": {\"B\": $util.dynamodb.toBinary($ctx.args.approved)},\n    },\n  },\n  \"index\": \"approved-index\",\n  \"limit\": 20,\n  \"nextToken\": null,\n  \"scanIndexForward\": true,\n  \"select\": \"ALL_ATTRIBUTES\",\n}\"; line: 10, column: 31]'

Any idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$util.dynamodb.toBinary(String data)` takes a `String` as input, but you are passing a `Boolean` and this is why it fails evaluation.

This is good feedback, I will check with the team if it's possible to make the utility more lenient and take a Boolean as well `$util.dynamodb.toBinary(Boolean data)`

Here is a possible workaround in the meantime:

```
#if($ctx.args.approved) 
 #set($approved = $util.dynamodb.toBinaryJson("true"))
#else
 #set($approved = $util.dynamodb.toBinaryJson("false"))
#end

{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Query",
  "query": {
    "expression": "#approved = :approved",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#approved": "approved",
    },
    "expressionValues": {
      ":approved":  $approved
    },
  },
  "index": "approved-index",
  "limit": $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.first, 20),
  "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.after, null)),
  "scanIndexForward": true,
  "select": "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. This works: `"expressionValues": { ":approved": {"B": "true"}, }`, and I would think `{"B": "${$ctx.args.approved}"}` or `$util.dynamodb.toBinary(Boolean.toString($ctx.args.approved))` could help, but no. The latter yields "Encountered \"),\\n    },\\n  },\\n  \\\"index\\\": \\\"approved-index\\\",\\n  \\\"limit\\\": \" at velocity[line 10, column 80]\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"[\" ...\n    \",\" ...\n    \")\" ...\n    <WHITESPACE> ...\n"

Comment: Sorry I read your question too fast. Velocity has some interesting ways to handle the Boolean type. I edited my answer.